# How to pass model from one View to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and i'm trying to rewrite my JS project in it, i have two pages in my project, the index and menu, from the index the user can just press the button to be redirected to menu or chose another language and be redirected to menu with that language.

In the index i'm loading from DB all the user infos like logo, background image and operations which the user can or can't do returned in a Model. **Once the user is redirected to menu i should reuse that user Model data**, but by looking around i've found that i should use something like TempData or ViewBag but neither of them worked for me.

So in index i have buttons like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Menu", "VMenu", new { lang = "IT" })'" id="menu" class="btn btn-sm animated-button thar-three">Menu</a>
```

Which redirect the user to menu by passing the language.

And my Controllers looks like this:

```
public class VMenuController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(AuthHelper.GetProfilo(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)); // returning Profilo model
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Menu(string lang)
    {
        return View(MenuHelper.GetMenu(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity, lang)); // returning Menu Model
    }

}
```

But i just can't get which should be the best way to pass the Profilo Model to Menu...

I've tryed by setting the TempData inside Index controller or even ViewBag but all of them returned null in Menu...

Comment: You don't pass models between actions. Instead, you recreate it upon each request. Using server side containers could mean unnecessary memory consumption.

Comment: @WiktorZychla so i have to call `AuthHelper.GetProfilo(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)` again in Menu() and set the Menu Model and Profilo Model in the same model to return it to the view? If so i'd store the Profilo in localstorage so it won't open again the connection with the database to get the user data again...

Comment: Yes, recreating upon every request would work. Storing it in a session (or temp data) means you waste server memory.

Comment: I agree with @WiktorZychla you just get your data again, although setting the data in localstorage (or session) would also work. I wouldnt use ViewBag or TempData for this. I have encountered a situation where the misuse of the ViewBag got into a stackoverflow exception :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla so i'd go for JS solution and i will just store it in browser localstorage to don't waste the server memory, thank for the advice about the memory consumption

Comment: @WiktorZychla restoring user info in Session wasn't that bad I believe. When you consider that information will be used most of page actions. Managing server memory is an important course to handle but db calls are real bottle necks for web applications.

Comment: @SüleymanSümertaş: the only problem with session is that you need to call these pages in particular order. If someone bookmarks a page that doesn't store the data in session, navigating to it can lead to multiple issues. And if that leads to a solution where you ultimately query and store the data into the session in **all** pages, the session becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have user profile info for every session. Why don't you store that information in Session object? As long as your session is alive you can get that profile info from every controller and method in your project.

```
public class VMenuController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var userProfile = AuthHelper.GetProfilo(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity); // fetch from db
        Session["UserProfile"] = userProfile; // set to session.

        return View(userProfile);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Menu(string lang)
    {
        var userProfile = Session["UserProfile"]; // get from session and use it wherever you like.

        return View(MenuHelper.GetMenu(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity, lang)); // returning Menu Model
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using anchor use html helper @Html.ActionLink or @Ajax.ActionLink to achieve your requirement. You can google for syntax for this helper method. TempData and ViewBag should also work in this case.